# What is the difference between fetch() and window.fetch()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

See the title. When calling fetch in our react project, a (now departed) developer originally used from fetch to window.fetch. I'm not sure of the difference and can't find anything conclusive online (W3Schools doesn't even mention fetch as a function of the window)

Comment: Fetch is a function on the window object. You don't need to specify `window.fetch` in most cases as the global scope is `window`. There is no difference.

Comment: press F12 and type `fetch === window.fetch`. Same thing.

Comment: W3Schools doesn't mention a lot of things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On your developer console, try this experiment:

```
fetch === window.fetch
```

You'll see that this returns `true`.  They are in fact the same thing.

`window` is the global object in a browser context.  The browser APIs (distinct from language features) are found on the global `window` object.

Comment: "Much of the framework you're using is built on the window object." --- this is a weird one.

Comment: @zerkms Feel free to re-word if you have a better way to describe it.

Comment: "All browser APIs are provided through the `window` global object." ?